# How to perform a function onRendered inside events?

Tags: javascript, meteor

How to perform a function `onRendered` inside `events`? The sample code below does not work. How is the correct syntax? If this is allowed, of course.

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  "click": function(event, template) {
    this.instance().onRendered(function() {
      alert('hello');
    });
  }
});
```

*Using Google Translate.*

Comment: ... Why do you want to set `onRendered` from a helper? The helper will always be executed _after_ the `onRendered` callback so I have troubles understanding the point of setting it after it should have executed.

Comment: I'm using Telescope.I need to get the template data context I click. If I use a helper he will return the context of all instances of the template and not the one I clicked. _Using Google Translate_.

Comment: What do you mean "the context of all instances of the template"? Why not use `Template.instance().data`? Or `this.data`?

Comment: If I do that it will return all instances of the template. Each post is an instance. Already in Template.xxx.events, it only returns the instance that I clicked. I do not know why. See http://demo2.telescopeapp.org. Each post is an instance of the template. _Using Google Translate_.

Comment: How can you click something that isn't rendered yet?

Comment: Already rendered. I want to click to render something else. I want to integrate [Blueimp Gallery](https://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/).

Comment: An event on a template should only return the data context of that instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Blaze.render](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_render).

If you just wanna get the data which bind to your item from your event handler, use

```
Blaze.getData(event.target)
```

[Reference is here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_getdata)